# Install MikTex in custom location Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, latex

I'm following [this guide](https://miktex.org/howto/install-miktex-unx) to install miktex in my Ubuntu 18.04. However, I want to install it in a custom location (`~/Softwares/MikTex`). Is it possible to do this? If yes how?

The reason I need to do this is because, in my laptop `root` has only 25GB and I've less than 10GB left. I don't want to use it up. However, `home` has around 250GB.

Comment: No problem to install Miktex and a lot more software with 10 GB left on a root partition. For a root partition, this is plenty of space. If you still want to move, the easiest procedure in your case would be to install it regularly, then afterwards move the folders where the MikTex files are installed, and in the original place, place a symbolic link that points to the new location.